# Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of undefined CJuiDatePicker yii

Tags: php, yii

I am currently using a CGridView which has a drop down box to change the status for a particular id. Upon changing the dropdown value, it shows a modal with an input field to select the date which uses 'CJuiDatePicker' extension provided by Zii. The idea is to store the status change date in the CGridView as well and all of it is done using ajax.

The problem i am currently facing is all of this works fine for the initial couple of times. But after sometime, when trying to select the date from the modal pop-up, I get "**Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of undefined**" error.

Below is the code that I have used:
Controller:

```
public function actionModalMessage() {
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';
    $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '';

    echo $this->renderPartial('message', array('id' => $id, 'value' => $value, 'type' => $type), false, true);
}
```

Modal View (message.php):

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'change-status-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('statistics/update'),
));
?>

<input name="id" id="RefundCheque_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input name="value" id="RefundCheque_value" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
<input name="type" id="RefundCheque_type" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $type; ?>">

<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'change_date',
    'options' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        "id" => "chagedate",
    ),
));
?>


<input type="submit" class='button blue change_status' value="Update"/>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double loading your js files, thats a problem. Here's solution to fix this:

**Add to your controller:**

```
   Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap["*.js"]=false;
   $this->renderPartial('message', array('id' => $id, 'value' => $value, 'type' => $type), false, true);
   Yii::app()->end();
```

So now you excluded loading js scripts when your ajax triggered.

**Now you need to register needed scripts in initial view.**

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
```

JqueryUI needed to use datepicker widget.